# HtmlAgilityPack: How to check if an element is visible?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am doing some HTML parsing and I am using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and I am trying to check if a node element would be visible if the html was rendered in a browser.

By visible, I am probably content with checking the `display` and `visibility` style values. (unless there is something additional I should worry about?).

So, how can I do this? Is there a build in easy way? Can I use some XPath magic? (I don't have too much knowledge of XPath at the moment).

I have thought about manually parsing the style value, but would rather save this as a last resort. Or is this my only option?

Just for reference, the object I am working with is something like this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node = GetNode();
```

Comment: This is not really feasible.  Visibility can be dictated by cascading styles (and X/Y positioning), for which you basically need a full-on DOM/CSS parser and implementation (i.e. a browser) to calculate.  (also, Javascript can manipulate visibility as well)

Comment: @KirkWoll: Good points. However, Javascript is not a factor here, and the Html is actually generated from applying an XSLT to an XML file. But I hear what you are saying about css files, that might throw in a spanner or two

Comment: @musefan not an easy task (at all). There are lots of factors to consider here. For example, it might be inside a hidden container (as you said), or the position of the element could be negative (so that it doesn't appear on the screen). Some crawlers[citation required] do that to avoid cheating, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so I have managed to do this, at least for my needs. Please be warned however, as other comments have spoke of, this doesn't allow you to check if an element will be visible (on screen) for the end user.

The approach I have taken simple checks some basic rules: An element is "not visible" if the style attribute for the element contains `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`, OR an ancestor element has the same style rules.

With that in mind, here is my code that does the job for me:

```
private static bool IsNodeVisible(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node)
{
    var attribute = node.Attributes["style"];

    bool thisVisible = false;

    if (attribute == null || CheckStyleVisibility(attribute.Value))
        thisVisible = true;

    if (thisVisible && node.ParentNode != null)
        return IsNodeVisible(node.ParentNode);

    return thisVisible;
}

private static bool CheckStyleVisibility(string style)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(style))
        return true;

    var keys = ParseHtmlStyleString(style);

    if (keys.Keys.Contains("display"))
    {
        string display = keys["display"];
        if (display != null && display == "none")
            return false;
    }

    if (keys.Keys.Contains("visibility"))
    {
        string visibility = keys["visibility"];
        if (visibility != null && visibility == "hidden")
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static Dictionary<string, string> ParseHtmlStyleString(string style)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    style = style.Replace(" ", "").ToLowerInvariant();

    string[] settings = style.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (string s in settings)
    {
        if (!s.Contains(':'))
            continue;
        string[] data = s.Split(':');
        result.Add(data[0], data[1]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The entry point for this is `IsNodeVisible` and will check the visibility of the `HtmlNode` passed to it.

Comment: its parent maybe also invisible = makes invisible

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: I am not sure what you are trying to say, but my code *does* check the visibility of all parent/ancestor nodes

Comment: yes i saw later. however this still doesnt work when it has classes that hides the object :)

Comment: That's true, my needs were very basic at the time. I guess you could parse the CSS files too and search for any matching classes. It's a big overhead to add though... but you gotta do what you gotta do right... pretty difficult to get right though if you have even semi-complex CSS selectors