# VB.Net Copy all text from WebBrowser

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack

I want to copy all **visible** text from WebBrowser.

`Clipboard.SetText(WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText)`

This code is working, but it's also getting text between `<div style="display:none">` and `</div>`, which i don't want (i want only text that is visible when i manually go to that website).

Comment: Have you searched Google? Look into ***HtmlAgilityPack*** it will parse it for you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy all text from webbrowser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637192/copy-all-text-from-webbrowser-control)

Comment: I saw that thread, but i don't know C# or anyone that could translate it to me. Does anybody has an answer for this?

Comment: Have you simply tried googling _"Translate C# to VB.NET"_?

Comment: It always has errors when i convert C# to VB.Net and that code is not the one i'm looking for ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me against google.com.  This is mostly a translation of the c# version of the same question mentioned in the comments above.

```
    Dim text As String
    WebBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", False, Nothing)
    WebBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)
    text = Clipboard.GetText()
    MessageBox.Show(text, "Text")
```

Comment: This idea works, thank you for that. But, any ideas how to do this without using clipboard? Thanks again.

Comment: Attempts to do this without the clipboard will require serious XML parsing.

Comment: You can take a look at this post where they show how to check if an element is visible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776840/htmlagilitypack-how-to-check-if-an-element-is-visible

Comment: Once you know if it is visible, you could simply do a linq statement on the body like so :   Dim VisibleText = From element In  body.DescendantsAndSelf()
                          Where CheckIfVisible(element)
                          Select element.InnerText

Comment: I added Clipboard.Clear() and duplicated second line in your code, now it works perfectly for me. Thank you very much Alexander! :)